# Converting dataflash files from The Cube (CubePilot) to formats similar to what mission planner provides

Tags: mission-planner

After copying the files from the [SD card](https://docs.cubepilot.org/user-guides/autopilot/the-cube-user-manual#install-sd-card) from The Cube, I can use mission planner to convert the dataflash files (`.bin`) to `.gpx`, `.log` (which in many cases has been referred to as `.csv`) and even `.m` with the *Creat KML+GPX*, *PX4 bin to log*, and *Create matlab file* functionalities.
[image: DATAFLASH LOGS TAB]

Is it possible to do a similar thing via command line in python3 in windows and Linux?

---

**EDIT**:

I've found [something](https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/pymavlink-mavlogdump-py-usage-for-converting-bin-to-log/93725/2) about converting `.bin` to `.log` with the following:

```
$ mavlogdump.py --format csv --types '*' 00000047.BIN
```

however I'm running into a problem as [mentioned here](https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/pymavlink-mavlogdump-py-usage-for-converting-bin-to-log/93725/3) within the module.

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
  File "C:\Users\kyrlon\Downloads\BIN\pyvenv\Scripts\mavlogdump.py", line 222, in <module>
    match_types.append("FMT")
  File "C:\Users\kyrlon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\kyrlon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main (Current frame)
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

---

**EDIT2**:

Doing a test with only one type I get output finally to the console.

```
mavlogdump.py --types GPS --format csv 00000047.BIN
```

Running with the `--show-types` argument I can see all formats available for my specific `.bin` file

```
$ mavlogdump.py --show-types 00000047.BIN 
XKV1
MAG2
XKF6
TERR
CMD 
CTRL
TSYN
XKF8
ORGN
XKV2
DSF
RCIN
IOMC
POS
XKQ1
IMU3
XKF1
RCOU
POWR
RSSI
D32
PM
BAT
XKF4
MULT
CTUN
XKF5
XKF3
GPA
HEAT
XKF2
AHR2
RATE
XKT1
FMTU
LGR
IMU
MAG
BAR2
XKF9
GPS
VIBE
MODE
UNIT
IMU2
SRTL
XKQ2
XKT2
PARM
DU32
MOTB
PSC
FMT
RAD
RALY
ATT
EV
XKF7
MAV
MSG
BARO
MAVC
```